# NullPointerException when creating onClickListener

Tags: java, android, xml

Okay, I've created a very basic Android game. The simple idea is that when the user clicks the jump button, it calls the jump method. I'm using a XML file to declare the button, but I'm finding it throws a NullPointerException.

I've looked at other answers, and I realise that the most likely reason is because the button id isn't in the XML file (at least when it's being initialised). I've tried changing my code to match other answers here, but it's still throwing the exception.

Would anyone be able to take a look and just see? I'm fairly new (and hopeless) with anything Android, and would really appreciate the help.

---

The code (GameActivity.java):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
theView = (GameView)findViewById(R.id.gameView);
//Create jump button and link to jump event
    Button jumpButton = (Button)theView.findViewById(R.id.jumpbutton);
    jumpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
        //jump             
        theGame.getPlayer().jump();
        }
    });
```

The XML (main.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.RoundHouse.GoGoRunner.GameView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gameView"/>

<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/jumpbutton"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:clickable="true" android:background="@drawable/jumpbutton"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Again, apologies for asking what probably seems like a trivial question, but I've tried other Stack Overflow solutions with no positive outcome.

Comment: If you need debugging, adding the LogCat output helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your not calling the `Button` instantiation on the right view.

```
<com.RoundHouse.GoGoRunner.GameView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gameView"/>

<Button...
```

As you can see above the button does not reside in the `GameView` which is where you're looking for the button here...

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
theView = (GameView)findViewById(R.id.gameView);
//Create jump button and link to jump event
Button jumpButton = (Button)theView.findViewById(R.id.jumpbutton);
```

You get the `GameView` and call `findView...` on it. Just call it like...

`... = (Button) findViewById(...);`

Comment: I had a feeling that was likely to be the problem, but I'm not sure how to go about making that work? This is the first time I've really used XML...

Comment: @MargaretCarlin, If it's to be inside the view, and the view allows that, then you'd need to nest the button definition inside the `GameView`s. So you'd change the the tag at the end of the attributes to `>` instead of `/>` put the button after that followed by the `/>`.

Comment: Perfect! It works. Thank you so so much! I feel like a massive idiot, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks perfectly fine to me, which tells me there is probably a problem with your `R.java` file not being updated.

A quick fix is to go to your AndroidManifest.xml and simply type a space somewhere (literally press the spacebar), and then save it. If you want, you can then remove the space. It's a quick trick to get the R.java file to rebuild itself.

I've had this issue before and that is how I mitigated it.